# Script to run on specific sheet

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a script that I have been using, but it only works with, as written, the active sheet (pulls a list of documents from the specified directory in Google Drive).  How can transform this to run on a specific sheet.  The name of the sheet is "Per 7".

```
function list_all_files_inside_one_folder_without_subfolders(){
  var sh = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var folder = DriveApp.getFolderById('0B4zzmqQYDRm2flZPRFVWd1FfSGpJTXFmcWlSLXVVTUZJRjNlU3QzTER6aHFsYVEzTDdrS00'); // I change the folder ID  here 
  var list = [];
  list.push(['Name']);
  var files = folder.getFiles();
  while (files.hasNext()){
    file = files.next();
    var row = []
    row.push(file.getName())
    list.push(row);
  }
   sh.getRange(1,1,list.length,list[0].length).setValues(list);
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try changing:

```
 var sh = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
```

to

```
 var sh = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('Per 7');
```

Comment: Where do I insert the link to the sheet?  Or the name of the sheet?  "Per 7" is one sheet (tab) within the file.

Comment: Sorry, to clarify, I don't want to use the active sheet, but would like the script to run on the sheet when it's not open.

Comment: If you change the line I mentioned, whenever the script executes (and whatever the currently active sheet is) it will use the sheet 'Per 7' as the output sheet. The 'sheet' is a sheet (tab) in an spreadsheet (workbook).

Comment: So can I direct it to a non-active workbook then?  So it can run when it's not open?

Comment: That should indeed be possible. you can programmatically open the other workbook by using its id.. e.g: SpreadsheetApp.openById('id_of_the_other_spreadsheet) --> this returns a spreadsheet object.

Comment: Awesome!  Thank you.