# Running script to a specific sheet - Google sheet

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, triggers

I would like to know how to modify my script to target a specif tab (Check) and not all tabs. Below is my script:

```
function onEdit(e) {    
  var sheet, cols, colInd, offset, format;   
  sheet = e.source.getActiveSheet();
  cols = [7,13,14,16];
  colInd = cols.indexOf(e.range.columnStart);
  if (colInd == -1) return;
  if (colInd < 3) {
    offset = [4,-1,1,1];
    format = "MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss";
    e.range.offset(0, offset[colInd])
    .setValue(Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), "GMT+8", format));
  } else {
    setValidation(e);
  }
}
```

Here's my sample sheet: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1hQhh3UlWm38ILADMqlCuv08GipMBDWVOF4l4gzM5tjE/edit#gid=2039637864

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Script to run on specific sheet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35524955/script-to-run-on-specific-sheet)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After re-reading your question I think that what you mean is only executing the `onEdit` only when the Sheet `Check` is modified.

I that's the case you should just put an `if` statement to make sure that the edit is happening in the correct sheet. So using your original code that would work something like:

```js
function onEdit(e) {    
  var cols, colInd, offset, format;   
  if(e.range.getSheet().getName() = 'Check'){
    cols = [7,13,14,16];
    colInd = cols.indexOf(e.range.columnStart);
    if (colInd == -1) return;
    if (colInd < 3) {
      offset = [4,-1,1,1];
      format = "MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss";
      e.range.offset(0, offset[colInd])
      .setValue(Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), "GMT+8", format));
    } else {
      setValidation(e);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: After re-reading your question I have modified my answer. I think that what you meant was to only do action when the Sheet is `Check`. Tell me if that works. If not please clarify what is your expected behavior so I can give you a hand.

Answer (score 4):

Answer by [Raserhin](https://stackoverflow.com/users/11758896/raserhin) works if you want to get a reference to the 'Check' sheet when any of the sheets in the document is edited.

If you want to run the code ONLY when the 'Check' sheet is edited, then use the following code.

```
function onEdit(e) {

    var sheet, cols, colInd, offset, format;   
    sheet = e.source.getActiveSheet();
    if (sheet.getName() === 'Check') {  // Condition to check edited Sheet
        cols = [7,13,14,16];
        colInd = cols.indexOf(e.range.columnStart);
        if (colInd == -1) return;
        if (colInd < 3) {
            offset = [4,-1,1,1]
            format = "MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss";
            e.range.offset(0, offset[colInd])
            .setValue(Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), "GMT+8", format));
        } else {
            setValidation(e);
        }
     }
}
```